# Why is my SQL Query returning multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, join, compare

I have two tables and I am trying to retrieve the thread-id corresponding to the max(id) (which is incremented) of the first table and the user id of the second table.  In the sql statement, I have joined the tables and tried to retrieve the column, but am receiving multiple rows and I am not sure why.  I put an example user ID of 1 and I am expecting a retrieval of only one row, which should have a value of 85.

In spelled out words, I want to get the thread-id from Table 1 that corresponds to the user_id of Table 2 and the maximum id of Table 1.

I have the fiddle below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a7d5d/56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
  $table_messages.thread_id
FROM 
  $table_messages 
RIGHT JOIN 
  $table_recipients ON $table_messages.thread_id = $table_recipients.thread_id
WHERE 
   user_id = 1 
order by $table_messages.id DESC
Limit 0,1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was close to ready to bang my head against the wall

Answer (score 0):

In your last line you have the following `SELECT` statement:

```
    (SELECT MAX($table_messages.id))
```

However, you have not specified which table to get this value from. Change this statement to:

```
    (SELECT MAX($table_messages.id) FROM $table_messages)
```

This should now return one row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this seems to not return the logic that I was looking for.  Something breaks the query.